# Julia Pkg.add persistent errors

Tags: julia

I've encountered another problem with Julia's Pkg.add on Windows8 and the x64 distro. I started with a fresh install and couldn't blame it on dependencies.

```
 ERROR: key not found: "StatsBase"
```

Reinstall & clearing Julia variables from the systems didn't help so I'm below what finally did the trick, after 4 hours of fumbling around. Hope it's of use.

Answer (score 2):

After re-installing Pkg.init() didn't help, because the package folder was stored in Users/./.julia/ . The trick was to wipe all the directories previously associated with Julia, reinstall and then do Pkg.init().